# Global Ignore Pattern for Subversion

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have the following ignore in my Tortoise settings:

```
*.pdb *.suo *.user *.cache */_ReSharper */bin */obj *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
```

But bin and obj folders as well as reSharper still get submitted.

Second, is there a way in Windows if using Tortoise and Visual SVN Server to specify this globally on the server or something so that not every individual developer needs to manually specify these settings?  I don't want to rely on our developers having to do this themselves and want to control this globally for obvious maintenance and standards reasons.

Comment: Just to note, if you've versioned a file or folder within bin or obj, they will still appear in the commit list if they've changed.

Answer (score 3):

Both the global ignore pattern and the svn:ignore property only work on **unversioned** files and folders. Once they're versioned, they won't be ignored anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to set the ignores in the repository itself to avoid the problem of a developer not having their global ignore pattern set.